# Django with docker-compose : OperationalError: FATAL: database "" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am currently on a project based around react in the frontend, django in the backend, postgresql for the database and nginx for the reverse proxy. Everything is linked up with a Docker-compose file.

My previous question asked in this forum was about linking the database to the django backend. Altough it was resolved, I have another problem now : when I try to create a superuser account in the container, the container responds me with this error :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "" does not exist
```

One of my first try to solve it was to check if the database is correctly created. Unfortunately I do not why but neither the database nor the role is created.

- Docker-compose.yaml file :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: app_server_conf
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - PUBLIC_URL=127.0.0.1
    networks:
      app_network:
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/staticfiles

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: "make run"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/staticfiles/
    
  database:
    container_name: database
    build:
      context: ./postgres/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ['postgres', "-c", 'log_statement=all']
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=
      - POSTGRES_USER=
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - app_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d","db_prod"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  postgres_init:
  staticfiles:
  static:

networks:
  app_network:
    name: Application network
```

- .env:

```
DEBUG=

ALLOWED_HOSTS=''

SECRET_KEY=

POSTGRES_HOST=
POSTGRES_PORT=
POSTGRES_ENGINE=
POSTGRES_DB=
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
```

- settings.py (database part):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST","localhost"),
        'PORT':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT","5432"),
        'NAME':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_NAME","test"),
        'ENGINE':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_ENGINE","django.db.backends.postgresql"),
        'USER':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER","test"),
        'PASSWORD':os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD","test"),
    }
}
```

- Dockerfile for the database :

```
FROM postgres:latest
CMD ["postgres"]
```

I have checked and both the values entered in the .env file and in the environment variables are the same.

I thank anyone which will try to help me resolve this problem.

Comment: I have found the answer : apparently, the database was created.